# How to conditionally assign values in SQL using case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, plsql

I would like to assign value to a variable based on a series of conditions. I can do this with IF/ELSE as shown by the followning code:

```
DECLARE @param1 VARCHAR(100) = 'value1';
DECLARE @param2 AS Varchar (25) = 'value2';
DECLARE @param3 AS Varchar (25) = 'value3';
DECLARE @param4 AS Varchar(25) = 'value4';

SELECT @param1 = @param1 + '_' + @param2;
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@param3) > 0 AND LEN(@param4) > 0
       SELECT @param1= @param1+ '_' + @param3 + '_' + @param4;
    ELSE
    IF LEN(@param3) > 0
       SELECT @param1= @param1+ '_' + @param3;
    ELSE IF LEN(@param4) > 0
    SELECT @param1= @param1 + '_' + @param4;
END
```

I'd like to replace the IF/ELSE with CASE, WHEN/THEN. something like:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN LEN(@param3) > 0 AND LEN(@param4) > 0 THEN  
        @param1 = @param1 + '_' + @param2 + '_' + @param3 + '_' + @param4
    WHEN LEN(@param3) > 0 AND LEN(@param4) <= 0 THEN  
        @param1 = @param1 + '_' + @param2 + '_' + @param3
    WHEN LEN(@param3) <= 0 AND LEN(@param4) > 0 THEN 
        @param1 = @param1 + '_' + @param2 + '_' + @param4
    ELSE @param1 = @param1 + '_' + @param2
```

Answer (score 5):

A `CASE` clause is an expression that returns a value. So you can't do an assignment from within the `CASE`.  But you can assign the result of the `CASE` to a variable.

```
SELECT @param1 = CASE 
    WHEN LEN(@param3) > 0 AND LEN(@param4) > 0 THEN  
        @param1 + '_' + @param2 + '_' + @param3 + '_' + @param4
    WHEN LEN(@param3) > 0 AND LEN(@param4) <= 0 THEN  
        @param1 + '_' + @param2 + '_' + @param3
    WHEN LEN(@param3) <= 0 AND LEN(@param4) > 0 THEN 
        @param1 + '_' + @param2 + '_' + @param4
    ELSE 
        @param1 + '_' + @param2
    END
```

Comment: Was this helpful at all?